# How can i get a data according to their id

Tags: angular

Lets say i have this table,Below specified is my data

```
Id , Name  , IsBillable
1    One       1
2    two       0
3.   three     0
```

So i stored all the above data in masterData by using get method.Lets assume this part.
So i'm using masterData to display my dropdown value.

```
 <mat-option *ngFor="let option of masterData " [value]="option.id">
                        {{option.value}}
  </mat-option>
```

So here ill get the selected ID. But i wanna get the isbillable data for selected Id by using some logic.Below code is my form

```
  const configControls = {
        
          'Id': [appointmentObj.Id, Validators.required],
          'IsBillable' : [appointmentObj.isBillable,Validators.required],
        
          
        }
        this.appointmentForm = this.formBuilder.group(configControls);
```

So i can get the selected Id by using this logic

```
this.appointmentForm.get('Id').value
```

But my main question is that is there any logic that i can use to get the isbillable data according to the selected ID.I tried by comparing masterData and     this.appointmentForm.get('Id').value but doesn't work.

```
var ApptId = this.appointmentForm.get('Id').value
    var getAppId = this.masterData[0].id
    for(getAppId = 0 ;getAppId <= ApptId;getAppId++){
      if(ApptId == getAppId){
       var billable = this.masterData [0].isBillable;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you use the entire object as the value of your formControl ? so you will have an access to the id and an acess to the isBillable propertie in the typescript.
The html will be :

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of masterData " [value]="option">
                        {{option.id}} <!-- if you want to display the id -->
 </mat-option>
```

and the typescript code to get the isBillable propertie from the selected value :

```
var billable = this.appointmentForm.get('Id').value.isBillable;
```

You will have to rename the formControl "id" since its not just an id anymore

Comment: i cannot send entire object to the API. I just need the Isbillable data for some verfication at the frontend side

Comment: when you make your api call just select the data your need (if you need the id) : 
    this.appointmentForm.get('Id').value.id

Comment: i have tried the above logic but [value]="option" if i use this i'm sending the entire object to the API.I just need to send only the id. Why i need isbillable data is just for some verification at the frontend side

Comment: can i see the code where you're making the api call ?